# Lost on startActivity in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I want to have my Floating Action Button open the activity "add", but I am lost on startActivity (line 9). Everything I do just says 'expression expected'. Please Help!

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Snackbar.make(view, "Do you want to open the activity?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                   .setAction("YES", new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                         startActivity(THIS IS WHERE I AM LOST);
                       }
```

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class));`

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `onClick(View view)` method use below code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DesiredActivity.class);
//Add extra if you want
intent.putExtra(Key, value);
startActivity(intent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the desired activity's intent in the `startActivity();`

for example suppose that user clicks on `Yes` and as a result you want to run the `DesiredActivity.class`. So you should have:

```
Intent desiredActivityIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DesiredActivity.class);

startActivity(myActivity);
```

So when user clicks `Yes` , that activity will run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this,activityWhereYouWantToGo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

where activityWhereYouWantToGo is your next activity name and yourCurrentActivity is your current activity name or you can simply pass activity context. just pest this code in on
public void onClick(View v) { }